# How to plot SP object as SF, in R leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet, gis, shapefile, r-sf

I just got started with GIS so please don't be mean.

I'm trying to plot different shp files, but this one particular file isn't plotting onto my interactive map I built which uses the leaflet package.

The file itself loads in R fine, but when I insert it into my map it looks super zooms out and looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmdPJ.png)

so I ran this code "attributes(geometry)"
and this came up -

```
$generic
[1] "geometry"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"

$package
[1] "sp"

$group
list()

$valueClass
character(0)

$signature
[1] "obj"

$default
`\001NULL\001`

$skeleton
(function (obj) 
stop("invalid call in method dispatch to 'geometry' (no default method)", 
    domain = NA))(obj)

$class
[1] "standardGeneric"
attr(,"package")
[1] "methods"
```

To me it seems like I'm dealing with "sp" and not "sf".. and something needs to be done about it?

Also this part "stop("invalid call in method dispatch to 'geometry' (no default method)" seems weird too.

Could you please help me fix this?

I'm trying to plot by using the "addPolygons" function in leaflet.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you used `rgdal::readOGR()` to read the shapefile; it produces a `Spatial` object (in the realm of {sp}, not {sf}).

I suggest you consider `sf::st_read()` to get the shapefile into R; it should behave better then.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response - I used the "sf::st_read" function to import the file, and the shp file itself is fine when it's imported but when i load it onto my interactive map it totally messes up everything. Everything is super zoomed out ... do you know why it does this?

Comment: I added a photo in my original post, so that you can see!

Comment: @Hibyetree this is the default - entire world, with no data shown. Does regular plot show anything? what does `sf::st_crs()` tell you? it should be EPSG:4326 (= WGS84), if it is not then pipe the object to  `st_transform(4326)`

Comment: Yes - when I run CRS I get this: " +proj=aea +lat_0=0 +lon_0=25 +lat_1=20 +lat_2=-23 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs "
, and when I run the class function on it I got "sf", "tbl_df", "tbl", and "data.frame".

Comment: And yup - the regular plot does show a bunch of maps, so it works.. It's just when I try to add it to my leaflet map it zooms out like that :( not sure why the "sp" thing is there either..

Comment: That looks like a CRS mismatch. Your object has as units meters; leaflet needs a degree based CRS. The standardization is required to use the various basemaps. Try plotting `st_transform(your_object, 4326)` instead.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response, I did and it still loads the default world map.. If I compare the crs of the map that does load successfully, it looks like this "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs "

If I take the crs of the one that I'm still trying to load, it says this 
" +proj=aea +lat_0=0 +lon_0=25 +lat_1=20 +lat_2=-23 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs "
Would you be able to see what's up with these two?

Comment: Sorry about the barrage of random codes, I'm not sure how to show you what I'm seeing!

Comment: I am afraid this is about what I can do without actually seeing your code & data :( You seem to have an issue with projection (the proj string is not compatible with leaflet.js requirements) but without actually seeing your data I can't help you further

Comment: Gotcha - thank you so much anyways :) I learned a lot!! You've been super helpful.

Comment: Wait! The 'st_transform' function totally just worked, I didn't save it as a separate variable earlier when I was trying to fix the crs. I tried and now my map totally works so thank you SO much!!

Comment: @Hibyetree glad to hear that! 